# Символизация LineString в Openlayers

Tags: css, style, openlayers

Не могу понять как задать стиль линии для отображения в виде черно-белой полоски или ломанной (в виде забора или ступенек)

1. Ломанная: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
2. Черно-белая: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Такая символизация часто встречается на схемах или гостах, но такой стиль не получается задать ни в OpenLayers, ни в ol-ext.

Может кто сталкивался с подобным или видел примеры в сети - подскажите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Ломанная (подсказали [здесь](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/411008)):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.6.1/css/ol.css" />
    <style> html, body, #map { margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 100%;  height: 100%; } </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.6.1/build/ol.js"></script>
    <script>
        var raster = new ol.layer.Tile({
            source:  new ol.source.OSM() 
        });

        var style = [
            new ol.style.Style({
                stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                    width: 5,
                    color: 'black'
                })
            }),
            new ol.style.Style({
                stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                    width: 3,
                    color: 'white',
                    lineCap: 'butt',
                    lineDash: [9, 9]
                })
            })
        ];

        var source = new ol.source.Vector();

        var vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
            source: source,
            style: style
        });

        var map = new ol.Map({
            layers: [raster, vector],
            target: 'map',
            view: new ol.View({
                center: [-11000000, 4600000],
                zoom: 4
            })
        });

        map.addInteraction(new ol.interaction.Draw({
            source: source,
            type: 'LineString',
            style: style
        }));
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

2. Географическая или черно-белая (подсказали [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69073845)):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.6.1/css/ol.css" />
    <style> html, body, #map { margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; }</style>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.6.1/build/ol.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjs/9.4.4/math.min.js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
<script>
    function styleFunction(width, strokeWidth, color) {
      var style = new ol.style.Style({
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
          color: color,
          width: strokeWidth
        })
      });
      return function(feature, resolution) {
        var lines = [];
        var geom = feature.getGeometry();
        if (geom.getType() == "LineString") {
          for (var line = 0; line < 2; line++) {
            var dist = width * resolution * (line - 1/2);
            var coords = [];
            var counter = 0;
            geom.forEachSegment(function(from, to) {
              var angle = Math.atan2(to[1] - from[1], to[0] - from[0]);
              var newFrom = [
                Math.sin(angle) * dist + from[0],
                -Math.cos(angle) * dist + from[1]
              ];
              var newTo = [
                Math.sin(angle) * dist + to[0],
                -Math.cos(angle) * dist + to[1]
              ];
              coords.push(newFrom);
              coords.push(newTo);
              if (coords.length > 2) {
                var intersection = math.intersect(coords[counter], coords[counter+1], coords[counter+2], coords[counter+3]);
                coords[counter+1] = (intersection) ? intersection : coords[counter+1];
                coords[counter+2] = (intersection) ? intersection : coords[counter+2];
                counter += 2;
              }
            });
            lines.push(new ol.geom.LineString(coords));
          }
          var length = geom.getLength();
          var intervals = Math.ceil(length / (width * resolution));
          var coords = [];
          coords.push(geom.getCoordinateAt(0));
          for (var i= 0; i < intervals; i++) {
            coords.push(
              lines[i % 2].getClosestPoint(
                geom.getCoordinateAt((2 * i + 1) / (intervals * 2))
              )
            );
          }
          coords.push(geom.getCoordinateAt(1));
          style.setGeometry(new ol.geom.LineString(coords));
          return style;
        }
      };
    }


    var raster = new ol.layer.Tile({
      source:  new ol.source.OSM() 
    });

    var source = new ol.source.Vector();

    var vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
      source: source,
      style: styleFunction(4, 2, 'black')
    });

    var map = new ol.Map({
      layers: [raster, vector],
      target: 'map',
      view: new ol.View({
        center: [-11000000, 4600000],
        zoom: 4
      })
    });

    map.addInteraction(new ol.interaction.Draw({
      source: source,
      type: 'LineString',
      style: styleFunction(4, 2, 'red')
    }));
</script>
</body>
</html>
```